# I want to make seo friendly url using .htacess, my webpages are in php, I want to make it .html extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am developing a website in my localhost using xampp. I want to make SEO friendly url like this.

Currently I access the page like this,
http://example.com/myproject/page.php?id=10

I want to change this as bellow,
http://example.com/myproject/page.html?id=10

I tried this using .htaccess, but sometimes I found it redirecting to .php, but I don't like so. I need permanent fix. So when user type .html it will access .php files, but no extension will change on their browser.

Comment: There is no SEO benefit to the change you're proposing.

Comment: `page.html?id=10` , if you are making extension as `.html` then using GET makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

when you will access page1.html the system will look for: page1.php